# index.fcgi renders as text on CENTOS 6.8 - django website

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, cpanel

I have a dedicated server with WHM, and I need to migrate a Python website to a user inside that server.

I am not familiar with python so I started looking for an index.php or index.html file but could not find any.

After investigation, I tried to execute the file manage.py, it was giving several errors and found that django was not installed, so after completing the install, the manage py file shows now some text with python commands and does not give any errors, you can visit it at http://mgtransportes.com.co/cgi-bin/manage.py

I have been reading that in order to show the website, I need to create a file called index.cfgi, and I did, but when opening the URL from the browser I get plain text, you can visit the naked domain (I cannot add more links due to my current reputation)

I am not sure how to enable FastCGI from WHM, and I do not even know if this is going to work, I have followed different tutorials, and looks like python is correctly installed, I have a test file on /cgi-bin/test.py and I prints a message as intended.

I am not sure how to execute the python script and show it as a normal website, I have been reading for hours and the best approach I could find is the index.cfgi file on the public_html directory.

Here is the content of my .htaccess on /public_html

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
DirectoryIndex index.fcgi

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.fcgi$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.fcgi/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here is the content of the index.cfgi file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import os
import sys

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/mglaggak/public_html/cgi-bin")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "webapp.settings"

WSGIServer(get_wsgi_application()).run()
```

I could create new python projects and they work!. But I am not sure what would be the best approach for existing websites, here is a video on the guy that gave me the backup files, but looks like he is executing the website on a localserver.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF2Eqi7JaFk

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: fcgi was deprecated in django 1.7 and has been removed in django 1.9 use uwsgi